Can you use an agent in a Router Chain?
Is it possible to utilize agents within router chains? I recently encountered an article addressing the topic about different chains. Given I have different use cases, each necessitating the triggering of different chains with the output sourced solely from the agent, routing should be managed through chains.
Link to the article: A Comprehensive Guide to Using Chains in Langchain
Could someone recommend the optimal approach to accomplish this task?
